# Wrong Action selected by @Url.Action (AttributeRouting, asp.net mvc 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, attributerouting

I have a controller who has this two action methods:

Both have the same name, but have different parameters, one of them is **HttpGet**, one is **HttpPost**

```
public class TestController : Controller {

    [Route("Test/{id:int}/ActionName"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ActionName(int id) { ... }

    [Route("Test/ActionName"), HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(TestObject obj) { ... }
}

public class TestObject {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I do `@Url.Action("ActionName", new { id = 3 })` I expect the HttpGet action to be selected, but instead the HttpPost action is.

I'm aware that if I set the Order to 1 in the first route, and 2 in the second, it works as expected, but I want to know why it's not getting selected in the first place.

Comment: `@Url.Action("ActionName", new { id = 3 })` will output `/Test/ActionName/3` - i.e. a `string` (it does not _select an action_). What do you mean _but instead the HttpPost action is selected_? There is nothing in the code you have shown relating to making a GET or POST to either of those methods.

Comment: I´m not making a GET or a POST, simply, in my understanding, `@Url.Action("ActionName", new { id = 3 })` should select a route matching both the action name and the parameters specified, meaning it should be getting the url  `Test/{id:int}/ActionName`

Comment: It will. But what do you mean _instead the HttpPost action is_?

Comment: What I mean is that `@Url.Action` is returning me the Url specified in the second action result (The one with HttpPost), not the first one.